# Query M1 database for ALL images and their expected locations?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, product-images, sql

We recently completed a migration from M1.9 to M2.1.9 however, there seems to be the odd missing picture. What I'm hoping to do is run a query to identify ALL images that are listed in Magento 1 DB with the expected file location and file name, and then compare that to a list of images that were successfully copied to our M2 installation, and identify those missing images.

Does anybody know the SQL queries I can run to identify all images in M1.9 database?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057034/which-magento-table-contains-product-image-names

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to check `catalog_product_entity_varchar` first. Image "names" are stored in `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` table, but the DB value already contains *subfolder prefixes*:

So for your `product_image.png` the entry is `/p/r/product_image.png`.

Raw SQL for filename ad location could look like:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(value, 6) as 'file',
  CONCAT('your_magento_url/media/catalog/product', value) as 'path'
FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery;
```

... or for php script ...

```
$path = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog' . DS . 'product';

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$read = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = $read->select()
    ->from($resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery'), array('file', 'path'))
    ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
    ->columns('SUBSTRING(value, 6) as file')
    ->columns('CONCAT("' . $path . '", value) as path');

$images = $read->fetchPairs($query);
```

This would give you an array like

```
array(
   'product_image.png' => 'full/path/to/product_image.png',
   ...
);
```